# How to create git branch from existing project

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have a project not by git and want to merge it with other one under git.
Wat will be steps to do this?

```
git init
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:projectname/reponame.git
git pull origin master
```

And then git wants me to commit anything to create local master branch.

```
git add something
git commit -m 'Initial'
```

But I want do this like a new branch, ok make new branch

```
git branch newbranch
git checkout newbranch
```

So what next? I want keep my master and merge it to newbranch.
When i try pull again i got this:

```
git pull origin master
From bitbucket.org:projectname/reponame
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        .gitignore
        .htaccess
        ...
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

How to tell git - ok do it!
At the end I want to have two branches: master (as it was at origin) and merged newbranch (my existed code + origin/master)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you are trying to merge your new branch with the master branch.In that case, you need to first checkout your master rather than pulling it first,

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge <your new branch name>
git push origin master
```

Also, what can be done is the latest changes done on the branch can be merged with master using git rebase option

```
git checkout <branch name>
git rebase master
```

What it will do is, will apply the changes done recently on the top of master.
After this, you can checkout the master branch and do a quick merge.

```
git checkout master
git merge <branch name>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to commit all your code.

Once the code is committed checkout the branch which you want to keep the content of. Execute `git merge` and you have any conflicts checkout the required files which you want to keep.

For example:

```
# Checkout the required branch (local or remote)
git checkout master

# merge the branches
git pull origin master

# in case you have conflicts:
# If you want to keep the version of your master use the --ours flag
git checkout --ours <file>

# second option if to merge use the merge strategy 
git merge -s recursive -X ours <branch>
```